# Ajax call causing freeze on Edge, blocking cookies helps

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

This bug appears only on Edge and IE.
I have a AJAX call on mainpage. When I redirect to another subpage (there is another AJAX call also) for the first time everything is OK. Then I back to mainpage and when I want to visit this subpage again, Edge freeze.
Blocking cookies fix this problem. Also when I delete manual session cookies, it loads properly.
Here is a screenshot of cookies: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Do6.png 
It only happens when I redirect from page that uses AJAX, from the standard one, it works perfectly.
There is a code:

`$.ajax({
    type: \'GET\',
    url: "/site/movies?nocache="+Math.random(),
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: \'html\',
    cache:false,
    data:{
         page_number: "'.$_GET['page-number'].'",
         search: "'.$_GET['search'].'",
         category: "'.$_GET['category'].'"
    },
    beforeSend: function (x) {
        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
        x.overrideMimeType(\'application/json;charset=UTF-8\');
        $(".all-movies").html("LOADING");
    }
    }, success: function (data) {
        $(".all-movies").empty();
        $(\'.all-movies\').html(data);
    }, error: function (data) {
    }
    });';`


Removing ajax call from mainpage doesn't help. Edge still freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the low amount of information about the problem, that you gave us, i can just suppose that you have a control working on cookies if they are just registered and it'is going in loop

**Edit after your new information:**

```
     page_number: "'.$_GET['page-number'].'",
     search: "'.$_GET['search'].'",
     category: "'.$_GET['category'].'"
```

This is the problem, it doesn't make sense at all, maybe the possibility to see the result handler can help us to help you

Comment: Deleting this doesn't help

Comment: Show us the handler of your ajax result